# Enabling & Disabling Drop Down Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form with two drop down lists.

1. The 1st drop down list contains 2 values &
2. the 2nd drop down list contains 3 values.

My objective is, when I select the `1st value` of the `1st drop down list`, the `2nd dropdownlist` should not be `visible`, but when i select the `2nd value` of the 1st `dropdownlist`, the 2nd `dropdownlist` should `appear`.

Comment: your title say enabling and disabling but in the body it is of visibility? what do you want to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **enable** and **disable** you can use this Code

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

You need to set **AutoPostBack="true"** and in the **SelectedIndexChanged** write this code

```
 protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            try
            {
                if (ddl1.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                ddl2.Enabled = false;
                //ddl2.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ddl2.Enabled = true;
                //ddl2.Visible = true;
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               string b=  ex.Message;
            }

    }
```

For **VISIBLE** **enabling/disabling** USE the **commented line** and comment the other line

Hope this helps

Happy coding

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the AutoPostBack-property of your first drop down list to true and add an OnSelectedIndexChanged-EventHandler

```
<asp:DropDown id="FirstList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FirstList_Changed"></asp:DropDown>
```

In your EventHandler you can check the selected index and act accordingly.

```
protected void FirstList_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(FirstList.SelectedIndex == 0) {
        SecondList.Visible = false;
    } else {
        SecondList.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

However you can also do the same thing with JavaScript (see BPX's solution).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using JQuery. A sample code is given below.

```
$("#DropDownList1").change(function(){
    indx = $("#DropDownList1 option:selected").index();
    if(indx==1)
    {
      $("#DropDownList2").hide();
    }
    else
    {
      $("#DropDownList2").show();
    }
})
```

Don't forget to add jquery plugin.